# MySQL complex query need suggestion

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table as follows:

```
 id | sender      | receiver    | time 
  1 | felix@a.com | lea@a.com   | 2014-07-04 22:50:16    
  2 | felix@a.com | lea@a.com   | 2014-07-04 22:51:20    
  3 | felix@a.com | mia@a.com   | 2014-07-04 22:51:41    
  4 | mia@a.com   | felix@a.com | 2014-07-04 22:52:45    
  5 | mia@a.com   | felix@a.com | 2014-07-04 22:52:58
  6 | lea@a.com   | felix@a.com | 2014-07-04 22:53:33
  7 | felix@a.com | mia@a.com   | 2014-07-04 22:55:53
```

I want to get distinct sender/receiver which has a entry with 'felix@a.com' order by time desc. So, output will be like below

```
 id | sender      | receiver    | time
  6 | lea@a.com   | felix@a.com | 2014-07-04 22:53:33
  7 | felix@a.com | mia@a.com   | 2014-07-04 22:55:53
```

I am trying with this but not working properly

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM  `message` 
ORDER BY  `time` DESC
) AS  `message` 
WHERE (
message.sender =  'felix@a.com'
OR message.receiver =  'felix@a.com'
)
GROUP BY message.receiver, message.sender
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: So you want the most recent row where sender = felix and the most recent row where receiver is felix? You can do this with UNION.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,sender VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL     
,receiver VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL    
,time DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'felix@a.com','lea@a.com','2014-07-04 22:50:16'),
(2,'felix@a.com','lea@a.com','2014-07-04 22:51:20'),
(3,'felix@a.com','mia@a.com','2014-07-04 22:51:41'),
(4,'mia@a.com','felix@a.com','2014-07-04 22:52:45'),
(5,'mia@a.com','felix@a.com','2014-07-04 22:52:58'),
(6,'lea@a.com','felix@a.com','2014-07-04 22:53:33'),
(7,'felix@a.com','mia@a.com','2014-07-04 22:55:53');

(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sender = 'felix@a.com' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE receiver = 'felix@a.com' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1);
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | sender      | receiver    | time                |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  7 | felix@a.com | mia@a.com   | 2014-07-04 22:55:53 |
|  6 | lea@a.com   | felix@a.com | 2014-07-04 22:53:33 |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry, it will work only for above input. What happened when 'felix@a.com' sends or receives to or from many users?

Comment: If the question changes, then the answer may too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender, receiver
FROM tablename ORDER BY time DESC;
```

This SQL DISTINCT clause example would return each unique sender and reciver combination. In this case, the DISTINCT applies to each field listed after the DISTINCT keyword.

Comment: Thank you but this is not giving my desired output